# Why can we check a user's regional settings by dividing two numbers in VBA?

Tags: vba, division, regional-settings

I'm working on a spreadsheet and trying to make sense of some of the code. The code below is (apparently) meant to return true if the user's regional settings accept "EN CDN". Can anyone give me some insight into how/why it works? I don't understand why the temp calculation would give an error and how that connects to the regional settings.

```
Function IsRegSettingsEn() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Err_Function

    Dim temp
    temp = CLng("2.0") / 2


    IsRegSettingsEn = True

    Exit Function
Err_Function:
    IsRegSettingsEn = False
End Function
```

Comment: All it seems to be testing is that a float converted to a string and then converted to a long will divide by 2 without any error... As to why, someone else might know better than i would, but it seems to have something to do with testing that type conversions are working as expected. Maybe look at how it's being used and that will give you more insight.

Comment: `CLng()` uses the user's locale to determine what's a valid "number", so if the user's decimal separator isn't `.` then the `CLng("2.0")` will throw a run-time error, causing the execution to skip over to the `Err_Function` line label, and the function will return False.

Comment: iIt seems that the assumption is that "2.0" will only convert to a number in case _the user's regional settings accept "EN CDN_ But I am pretty sure that this will not work because for me _Clng("2.0")_ is _20_ and no error will be thrown.

Comment: You should probaly use `Application.International` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.international

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce that clumsy method to:

```vb
Function IsRegSettingsEn() As Boolean

    IsRegSettingsEn = (Format(0, ".") = ".")

End Function
```

Comment: What about using `Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)` then?

Comment: @Storax: That's Excel-only, thus in, say, Access or PowerPoint will require a reference set to the Excel object library and the full syntax `Excel.Application.International(Excel.xlDecimalSeparator)`.

Comment: Yes, right. But OP says he is working on a spreadsheet, so my suggestion to use `Application.international` is IMHO okay. BTW, if you really want to find out regional settings with VBA only you should probably use an API call like `GetLocaleInfo`

Comment: That's right, but the question is not tagged Excel.